# I want to change html template to wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I moved my links of css and jquery from header.php and footer.php to enqueue.php and I called enqueue.php in the functions.php but it doesn't load my css and jquery in my site!!!!!!

```php
<?php

    function tecno_js_cs()
    {
         wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap',get_template_directory_uri().'/css/bootstrap.css', array(),'all'); 
         wp_enqueue_style('main',get_template_directory_uri().'/css/main.css', array(),  'all');  
         wp_enqueue_style('responsive',get_template_directory_uri().'/css/responsive.css', array(),'all');  
         wp_enqueue_style('style',get_template_directory_uri().'/css/style.css', array(),'all');  


         wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
         wp_enqueue_script( 'popper', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/popper.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
         wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap_min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
         wp_enqueue_script( 'mCustomScrollbar', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
         wp_enqueue_script( 'fancybox', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.fancybox.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
         wp_enqueue_script( 'appear', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/appear.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
         wp_enqueue_script( 'owl', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/owl.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
         wp_enqueue_script( 'wow', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/wow.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
         wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-ui.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );
         wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/script.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true );

    }

    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','tecno_js_cs');


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to create a function for that, you can call the CSS file in `header.php` itself. Just call it in the format:

```
<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/bootstrap.css
```

and call the scripts in `footer.php` by:

```
<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.js
```